# Why won't the socket open in bulk at once?

Tags: macos, sockets, go, nginx

OSX socket programming

Why won't the socket open in bulk at once?

I am using Intel macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

The connection test is being conducted with the local docker nginx server.

We are using Golang to conduct tests with the following codes:

```golang
func TestBulkConnection(t *testing.T) {
    var worker = 1000
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < worker; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        //time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)

        go func(id int) {
            conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9000")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            defer conn.Close()
            defer wg.Done()

            fmt.Println("waiting... ", id)
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 30)

        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

1000 goroutine connecting to nginx only.
After the connection, the sleep() function was used to make sure that nothing was done.

The client created 1000 goroutines, but found that only 200 to 300 nginx and connections worked and the rest did not (we confirmed with netstat-anv | grep 9000).

When connecting, it was confirmed that all connections are well established when the sleep() function is executed.

With nginx and client code, when spun from private ubuntu 18.04, the connection was confirmed at once.

I think it's a problem on the nginx server side, but I don't know the cause of the problem.

Is there a difference between Mac and Ubuntu in this test?

---

Added

```
let net = require('net');

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    const socket = net.connect({ port: 9000 });
    socket.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('connected to server!');
    });
}
```

netstat -anv | grep 9000 | wc -l

2000 connection ok

---

Added

The following links are used to increase the file descriptors of OSX.

https://wilsonmar.github.io/maximum-limits/

In recovery mode, 'csrutil disable' was also executed.

```
$ ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds) unlimited
-f: file size (blocks) unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes) unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes) 8192
-c: core file size (blocks) 0
-v: address space (kbytes) unlimited
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes) unlimited
-u: processes 2048
-n: file descriptors 524288
```

But still.

```
$ netstat -anv | grep 9000 | wc -l
287
```

Comment: How did the connections not work? Any errors on the client?

Comment: There's no error.

Comment: out of curiosity, does this work ? https://play.golang.org/p/-vXErq2f56M

Comment: @mh-cbon
waiting...
active 100
active 100
done waiting
active 0

Comment: so even go to go does not go higher than 100. Mayb below answer s correct idk.

Comment: Did you try counting the "waiting" output? Also what was the state of those 287 connections, "established" or smth else?

Comment: only est state and listen

Answer (score 0):

Every unix based OS has limits on the number of file descriptors a process can open. Also, every socket consumes a file descriptor, just like opening a file on disk or your `stdin`, `stdout` & `stderr`.

MacOS by default sets the limit of file descriptors to **256** per process. Therefore your statement that your Go process stops at around 200-300 connections sounds right. In theory it should stop being able to open sockets after **253** connections (3 file descriptors already assigned to stdin, stdout & stderr).

Ubuntu on the other hand sets the default limit to **1024**. You will still have this issue on Ubuntu but it will be able to open more sockets before you hit the wall.

On both systems you can check this limit by running the following command:

```
ulimit -n
```

Note: you can run `ulimit -a` to see all the limits.

On MacOS you can change this limit temporarily system-wide (it will reset after reboot) with the following command:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 1024 1024
```

On Ubuntu you can change this limit in your current shell with the following command:

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

This should let your 1000 connections to succeed. Note that the number does not have to be powers of 2. You can pass `1500` for example. Just remember that your process use file descriptors for things other than sockets.

Comment: how would that explain that OP said it was working fine with 2K conns using a nodejs script ?

Comment: Node.js may not open all connections at once. Specifically once the socket API returns an error node will queue your requests until it can open another socket. Go is much lower level so in Go, just like in C, you need to do this sort of thing yourself.